Spring Boot 3.3: Bypass @PreAuthorize Checks for SUPERADMIN Role
I’m working on a Spring Boot 3.3 (Spring Security 6.3.3) project and I need to programmatically bypass the @PreAuthorize checks on my controllers if the current Authentication has one specific authority: SUPERADMIN.
Essentially, if the authenticated user has the SUPERADMIN authority, I want to skip the @PreAuthorize checks and allow the request to proceed, thus confirming that the user is valid.
How can I achieve this? Is there a way to programmatically confirm a user with SUPERADMIN role and bypass any @PreAuthorize checks?
Here’s a simplified example of a controller:

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SOME', 'SOME2')")
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "This is a protected endpoint, but for SUPERADMIN everything is allowed";
    }
}

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Haven't done something like this specifically but I remember reading about AuthorizationManager. Write your own custom AuthorizationManager and register it in your SecurityFilterChain, that might work.

Are you bypassing all interceptors or just the PreAuthorize interceptor, if the former you can do like this:
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class PreAuthorizeAop {

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint p)  throws Throwable {
        if (isSuperAdmin() && p.getSignature() instanceof MethodSignature s) {
            return AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(p.getTarget(), s.getMethod(), p.getArgs());
        }
        return p.proceed();
    }

    private boolean isSuperAdmin() {
        return true;
    }

}

